# When radio button or checkbox checked, price calculated

Tags: android-studio, checkbox, radio-button

I am creating an app that allows user to make their own selection.

May I know how to make it calculate? It seems like the price is not included when radio button or checkbox is clicked. Please help me. Is it logically wrong or the syntax is wrong?

```
radioGroup1=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_1);

radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
    new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
            String tempSize="Choose your size";
            double SPrice=0;
            switch (radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
                case R.id.radioButton_munch:
                    tempSize="Personal Pan";
                    SPrice=5;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton_hungry:
                    tempSize="Regular Pan";
                    SPrice=9;
                    break;
                case R.id.radioButton_horse:
                    tempSize="Large Pan";
                    SPrice=12;
                    break;
            }
            Size.setText(tempSize);
            SizePrice = SPrice;
        }
    });

checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Topping = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_TopAns);
            Topping.setText(" ");

            if(ChkCheese.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + ChkCheese.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice=2.5;
            }
            if(ChkMushroom.isChecked()){
                Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkMushroom.getText().toString());
                ToppingPrice=1;
            }

        };
        ChkCheese.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
        ChkMushroom.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);

        TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
        Price.setText("$" + TotalPrice );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code:

```
TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
Price.setText("$" + TotalPrice );
```

inside the `onClick()` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Topping = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_TopAns);
        Topping.setText(" ");

        if(ChkCheese.isChecked()){
            Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + ChkCheese.getText().toString());
            ToppingPrice=2.5;
        }
        if(ChkMushroom.isChecked()){
            Topping.setText(Topping.getText().toString() + "," + ChkMushroom.getText().toString());
            ToppingPrice=1;
        }
        TotalPrice = SizePrice + CrustPrice + ToppingPrice;
        Price.setText("$" + TotalPrice );   

    };
```

so it is executed on every click on the checkbox.